# serialize/unserialize in jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Is there something like serialize/unserialize PHP functions in jQuery?

These functions return a string representations of an array or an object which can than be decoded back into array/object.

http://sk2.php.net/serialize

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery's serialize/serializeArray only works for form elements. I think you're looking for something more generic like this:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/

> This plugin makes it simple to convert to and from JSON:
>
> ```
> var thing = {plugin: 'jquery-json', version: 2.2};
>
> var encoded = $.toJSON(thing);        
> //'{"plugin":"jquery-json","version":2.2}'
> var name = $.evalJSON(encoded).plugin;
> //"jquery-json" 
> var version = $.evalJSON(encoded).version;
> // 2.2
> ```
>
> Most people asked me why I would want
>   to do such a thing, which boggles my
>   mind. Javascript makes it relatively
>   easy to convert from JSON, thanks to
>   eval(), but converting to JSON is
>   supposedly an edge requirement.
>
> This plugin exposes four new functions
>   onto the $, or jQuery object:
>
> - `toJSON`: Serializes a javascript object, number, string, or arry into JSON.
> - `evalJSON`: Converts from JSON to Javascript, quickly, and is trivial.
> - `secureEvalJSON`: Converts from JSON to Javascript, but does so while checking to see if the source is  actually JSON, and not with other Javascript statements thrown in.
> - `quoteString`: Places quotes around a string, and inteligently escapes any quote, backslash, or control characters.

Comment: Remember that JSON is a subset of Javascript -- if your Javascript object has functions in it then they can't be stored in JSON. If you object just contains hashes/arrays/data then JSON is sufficient.

Comment: how about json_decode? http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 3):

Why, yes: [jQuery's serialize](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize). To unserialize, you'd have to code a function yourself, esentially splitting the string at the &'s and then the ='s.

Comment: Oh but it only works on forms. What if I want to serialize an array I create in javascript code like this - var array = []; ?

Comment: You're correct, it only works on forms -- not on an array. Still, thanks for the two upvotes :)

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to serialize a form and then save it, and when the user returned to the form unserialize it and repopulate the data. Turns out there is a pretty sweet jQuery plugin for doing this already: [jQuery autosave](http://rikrikrik.com/jquery/autosave/). Maybe this will help out some of you.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like Chris' unserialize function for handling jQuery's serialized strings, however, don't forget to also urldecode() them on the server-side as data such as 'email' => 'me%40domain.com' will be coming in if you use the function as-is.

Updated:

```
function _unserializeJQuery($rubble = NULL) {
    $bricks = explode('&', $rubble);

    foreach ($bricks as $key => $value) {
        $walls = preg_split('/=/', $value);
        $built[urldecode($walls[0])] = urldecode($walls[1]);
    }

    return $built;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the native [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) library. For IE less than 8, you'll also need to use Crockford's [JSON.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/).

Answer (score 1):

Follow the variable "formdata" and look at the supporting code to see how I got this to work in a wordpress environment.

I'm using this on the client side (js):

```
// bind button, setup and call .ajax
jQuery('#submitbutton').click(function() {
    jQuery('#response_area').html('');

    // put all name-values from form  into one long string
    var serializedformdata = jQuery('#submitform').serialize();

    // configure array of options for the ajax call (can use a different action for each form)
    options = {
        type: 'POST',   
        url: sv_submitform_global_js_vars.ajaxurl,
        datatype: 'json',
        data: { 
            clienttime: getnow(),       
            sv_submit_form_check: jQuery('#sv_submit_form_check').val(),
            // this data:action:'value' is specifically required by the wordpress wp_ajax_<value> action hook to process the received data on the php/server side
            action: 'sv_submitform_hook',   
            formdata: serializedformdata,
            },
        beforeSend: beforesendfunc,
        // process returned json formatted data in function named below
        success: successfunc,  
    }
    // execute the ajax call to server (sending data)
    jQuery.ajax(options); 
});
```

... and this on the server side (PHP) to get the data back out and into a nice associative array for server side database work.

```
/////////////////////////////////////
//  ajax serverside data handler  ///
/////////////////////////////////////

// Add AJAX actions for submit form 
// Serves logged in users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_sv_submitform_hook', 'sv_submitform_handler' );
// Serves non-logged in users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_sv_submitform_hook', 'sv_submitform_handler' );


// this is the function that processes the input from the submit form
function sv_submitform_handler(){
    date_default_timezone_set('EST');
    $servertime = date('h:i:s a').' Server Time';   

    // fda = form data array can be used anywhere after the next statement. 
    // example: if ($fda['formfieldbyname'] == 'something'){...};
    parse_str($_POST['formdata'],$fda);  

    // this is how the nonce value is read  
    // form side is wp_nonce_field('sv_submitform','sv_submitform_check');
    if (!check_ajax_referer('sv_submitform', 'sv_submitform_check', false )){
            $data = $servertime . ' (Security Failed)';
        } else {
            $data = $servertime . ' (Security Passed)';
        };
    $returndata = array('data' => $data);

    exit(json_encode($returndata));
};
```

And for the WordPress coders out there, it took me a while to realize that the `wp_ajax_` hook had to be in either a plugin file or my child theme's functions.php.  It will not work in a normal page template!

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.4.1 of jQuery there is a jQuery.parseJSON() function built in.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently, I was using jQuery's .serializeArray() to post form data for validation via an AJAX call. On the server side I needed to split this object down into an associative array that would replicate the original $_POST data structure, so I wrote this little function:

```
function unserializeMe($obj) {
    $data = array();
    foreach($obj as $arr) {
        $data[$arr['name']] = $arr['value'];
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Then all you have to do is cast the input object to an array type before passing it in the funciton call:

```
$objData = (array) $_POST['data'];
$data = unserializeMe($objData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also wrote a function to parse the jQuery `.serialize()` function:

```
function createArray($rubble) {
    $bricks = explode('&', $rubble);

    foreach($bricks as $key => $value) {
        $walls = preg_split('/=/', $value);
        $built[$walls[0]] = $walls[1];
    }

    return $built;
}
```

Comment: This is PHP, not javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Use function [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

```
$array = array();
$string = "title=Hello&desc=World=&s[]=5&s[]=6&s[]=7";

parse_str($string, $array);
```

description on php.net