# How to remember form values across different pages?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need to send form values from one page to another and from that page to a third page. I would need the form values from the first page in the third page. How can I do it?

I have the code that transfers form values to the next page. How can I send the same form values to the third page?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">                                         
   // we will add our javascript code here           

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function(){

var str = $(this).serialize();

   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "contact.php",
   data: str,
   success: function(msg){

$("#note").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){

if(msg == 'OK') // Message Sent? Show the 'Thank You' message and hide the form
{
result = '<div class="notification_ok">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>';
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
$("#fields").hide();
}
else
{
result = msg;
}

$(this).html(result);

});

}

 });

return false;

});

});

 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **GET**

```
window.location.href = "http://yourdoamin?value= serialize text variable";
```

- [Get URL parameters & values with jQuery](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html)

Comment: thanks... how can i read the values in the third page when i use GET? any example would be great

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352214/serialize-unserialize-in-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using only simple values (not passing arrays), you can do something like this:

```
echo "<form id='second_page' method='post' action='third_page.php'>";
foreach ($x in $_POST) {
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . htmlspecialchars($x) . '" value="' . htmlspecialchars($_POST[$x]) . '" />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) - here is a [Tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php)

Comment: its just a html page.. not sure if we can sessions here

Comment: If you have php to send mail, return page 3 with the values in a new form. Or have the php send the values to page3

Answer (score 0):

You can set the values from Form #1 as [`input` tags with `hidden` type](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp) in Form #2. That way, when you submit Form #2, values will be available in Form #3.

Comment: i dont have form in the second page. its just that the second page is a php page which sends email after which the form values from the page1 is redirected to page3